# Why date dash expression disappear in .loc?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

When I checked what's the index name

```
df.index
```

it gave me

`DatetimeIndex(['2008-08-08'],['2008-08-09'] ,...., dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=100, freq=None)`

However, if I want to locate the row which include those index title, I had to type

```
df.loc['20080808' : '20080809']
```

to locate it. Can anyone explain it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is how the [document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) explained , also I think it can convert your input to the right datetime-format then do the slice

You can using

```
df.loc['2018-01-02':'2018-01-10']

df.loc['20180102':'20180110']
df.loc['01/02/2018':'2018-01-10']
```

or even

```
df.loc['01/02/2018':'20180110']
```